# Syntax Error in MySQL Stored Procedure when declaring variables

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a procedure to automatically add some values to a table, based on a couple of other tables.

These are the tables I have:

ENROLMENT table (where I store the programmes the students are enrolled in):

```
+----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ENROLMENT_NR   | int(10) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ENROLMENT_DATE | date    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| STUDENT_NR     | int(10) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| PROGRAMME_NR   | int(10) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

PROGRAMME_MODULE table (a Junction table which lists combinations of programmes and respective modules):

```
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| PROGRAMME_NR | int(10) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| MODULE_NR    | int(10) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

REGISTRATION table (where I want to store the students' registrations into the modules of each of the programmes they are enrolled in):

```
+-------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| REGISTRATION_NR   | int(10) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| REGISTRATION_DATE | date    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| MODULE_NR         | int(10) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| STUDENT_NR        | int(10) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I've never done a procedure in MySQL before. I did some basic ones with PL/SQL only. Based on some research, I created this procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS REGISTER_STUDENTS_PROC;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE REGISTER_STUDENTS_PROC()
DECLARE st_nr INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE prg_nr INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE enrl_date DATE DEFAULT '0000-00-00';
DECLARE mod_nr INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE ii INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE nn INT DEFAULT 0;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE ENROLMENT INTO n;
SET i=0;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE PROGRAMME_MODULE INTO nn;
SET ii=0;
BEGIN
WHILE i<n DO
    SELECT STUDENT_NR FROM TABLE ENROLMENT INTO st_nr;
    SELECT PROGRAMME_NR FROM TABLE ENROLMENT INTO prg_nr;
    SELECT ENROLMENT_DATE FROM TABLE ENROLMENT INTO enrl_date;
    BEGIN
    WHILE ii < n DO
        SELECT MODULE_NR FROM TABLE PROGRAMME_MODULE WHERE PROGRAMME_NR = prg_nr INTO mod_nr;
        INSERT INTO REGISTRATION (REGISTRATION_DATE,MODULE_NR,STUDENT_NR) VALUES (enrl_date,mod_nr,st_nr);
        SET ii = ii + 1;
    END WHILE;
    SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
END;
;;
```

This is the error I have:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE st_nr INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE prg_nr INT DEFAULT 0; DECLARE enrl_date DAT' at line 2.
```

One difficulty I find with SQL is that some errors are very unspecific, which constitutes an added challenge to a beginner... It's probably something basic but I can't see it.

Thank you

Comment: DECLARE must be in the BEGIN ..END block

Comment: You are right, how could I have missed that! Only now I have another error (ERROR 1064 (42000): (...) near 'TABLE ENROLMENT INTO n; SET i=0; SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE PROGRAMME_MODULE INT' at line 11) ... Shall I write a separate question or just edit the one above ?

Comment: Remove TABLE keyword `SELECT STUDENT_NR FROM ENROLMENT...` from all queries.

Comment: There seems to be one last thing at the end: (...) near 'WHILE; END' ?

Comment: Same generic error I'm afraid: "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHILE; END' at line 26"

Comment: try `END;; DELIMITER ;`

Comment: It will give me the same error after the procedure ends and only after that it will process DELIMITER ;

Comment: Maybe replace `DELIMITTER ;;` with `DELIMITER $$` and at the end `END$$ DELIMITER ;`

Comment: It will give me the same error, but I noticed that in spite of adding  `DELIMITER ;` at the end the delimiter remains the same, i.e. I have to use $$.

Comment: Make sure there is a space between delimiter and ;

Comment: Yes, I was copying and pasting in my last comment and there is a space as you can see :-(

Comment: Each BEGIN needs an END,you are missing an END.

Comment: Thanks, all the syntax errors are gone. Nothing happened, though. The table `REGISTRATIONS` is empty. But I'll open a separate question if I can't figure it out. If you'd like to write a solution with the corrections you made, I can mark it for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the comments from @Mihai, here is the code with no syntax errors:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS REGISTER_STUDENTS_PROC;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE REGISTER_STUDENTS_PROC()
BEGIN
DECLARE st_nr INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE prg_nr INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE enrl_date DATE DEFAULT '0000-00-00';
DECLARE mod_nr INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE ii INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE nn INT DEFAULT 0;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ENROLMENT INTO n;
SET i=0;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PROGRAMME_MODULE INTO nn;
SET ii=0;
WHILE i<n DO
    SELECT STUDENT_NR FROM ENROLMENT INTO st_nr;
    SELECT PROGRAMME_NR FROM ENROLMENT INTO prg_nr;
    SELECT ENROLMENT_DATE FROM ENROLMENT INTO enrl_date;
    BEGIN
    WHILE ii < n DO
        SELECT MODULE_NR FROM PROGRAMME_MODULE WHERE PROGRAMME_NR = prg_nr INTO mod_nr;
        INSERT INTO REGISTRATION (REGISTRATION_DATE,MODULE_NR,STUDENT_NR) VALUES (enrl_date,mod_nr,st_nr);
        SET ii = ii + 1;
    END WHILE;
    END;
    SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
END;
;;
```

---

So, there were three corrections:

1- Variables must be declared after `BEGIN`;
2- All `BEGIN` statements must be closed with `END` (the nested one wasn't closed);
3- Must use `SELECT FROM <<TABLE_NAME>>` and not `SELECT FROM TABLE <<TABLE_NAME>>`.